# Position, by word count, of all repetitions of a word in a text file

Tags: grep, wc

I want to find where a word appears in a text file — as in the number of words into the text that a word occurs — for all instances of that word, but I'm not sure even where to start. I imagine I'll need a loop, and some combination of grep and wc.

As an example, here is a an article about iPhone 11:

> On Tuesday, in a sign that Apple is paying attention to consumers who aren’t racing to buy more expensive phones, the company said the iPhone 11, its entry-level phone, would start at $700, compared with $750 for the comparable model last year.
>
> Apple kept the starting prices of its more advanced models, the iPhone 11 Pro and iPhone 11 Pro Max, at $1,000 and $1,100. The company unveiled the new phones at a 90-minute press event at its Silicon Valley campus.

There are 81 words in the text.

```
jaireaux@macbook:~$ wc -w temp.txt 
      81 temp.txt
```

The word 'iPhone' appears three times.

```
jaireaux@macbook:~$ grep -o -i iphone temp.txt | wc -w
       3
```

The output I want would be like this:

```
jaireaux@macbook:~$ whereword iPhone temp.txt 
      24
      54
      57
```

What would I do to get that output?

Comment: To get a robust answer you need to define a "word". In your example is `aren't` a word? Is `$1,000` a word? If so then they don't fit the usual criteria that a word is a series of word-constituent characters and the word-constituent characters are letters, digits, and underscore (e.g. see `-w` in the GNU `grep` man page, http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_man_pages/grep1.html, and the meaning of `\w` in regexps for tools that accept such). If `aren't` isn't a word then does that mean `aren` and `t` are both words?

Comment: Here's an example of one difficulty in coming up with a foolproof solution - is `'` part of a word or not? If you wanted to search for `aren't` then you'd want it to be part of a word but if you also wanted to find `iPhone` when `my iPhone's broken` appears in your text then you wouldn't want it to be part of a word. Lots of different conflicting possibilities to consider when trying to parse natural language!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's one way, using GNU tools:

```
$ tr ' ' '\n' < file | tr -d '[:punct:]' | grep . | grep -nFx iPhone
25:iPhone
54:iPhone
58:iPhone
```

The first `tr` replaces all spaces with newlines, and then the second deletes all punctuation (so that `iPhone,` can be found as a word). The `grep .` ensures that we skip any blank lines (we don't want to count those) and the `grep -n` appends the line number to the output. Then, the `-F` tells `grep` not to treat its input as a regular expression, and the `-x` that it should only find matches that span the entire line (so that `job` will not count as a match for `jobs`). Note that the numbers you gave in your question were off by one.

If you only want the numbers, you could add another step:

```
$ tr ' ' '\n' < file | tr -d '[:punct:]' | grep . | grep -nFx iPhone | cut -d: -f1
25
54
58
```

---

As has been pointed out in the comments, this will still have problems with "words" such as `aren't` or `double-barreled`. You can improve on that using:

```
tr '[[:space:][:punct:]]' '\n' < file | grep . | grep -nFx iPhone
```

Comment: That's perfect and way less complicated than I expected. Thanks!

Comment: A `tr -d [:punct:]` can be added, for the opposite reason as -x. "phone" (instead of iPhone) gives no match, but "phone," gives `29:phone,`

Comment: @rastafile ah, yes! Good catch, thanks.

Comment: @JohnnyRollerfeet you're very welcome. But please see the updated answer since rastafile correctly pointed out that the first version didn't handle punctuation correctly.

Comment: @terdon I noticed that when I ran it on the documents I'm using. I corrected it by taking the '-x' from the second grep.

Comment: @JohnnyRollerfeet that's not a good idea, that will make you find `NotAniPhone` as a match for `iPhone`. Better to remove the punctuation as rastafile suggested.

Comment: (1) Without the `tr`, “words” that consist only of punctuation (non-alphanumeric) characters count as words.  With the `tr`, they don’t count.  (Examples: “That will cost $$$.”, “They lived happily ever after -- except for the wolf.”, “Unix & Linux”, or the first sentence of the question.) (2) With the `tr`, if you want to look for “O'Reilly”, you have to search for `OReilly`.  Similarly, “entry-level” → `entrylevel`. … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) … (3) Using the style of Edgar Allan Poe as rendered [here](http://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/14082/pg14082.txt), “By that Heaven that bends above us--by that God we both adore” is 12 words, whose 7th word is either “us--by” or “usby”.  Closer to home, if you write “Unix&Linux” without spaces, it has the same problem.

Comment: The matched section being printed out is useful if you're searching for more than one word, or using wildcards. (e.g. grep -e "word" -e "other" will search with both "word" and "other" as patterns to match.)

Comment: @bobsburner hmm? The OP wanted the numbers and only one word. I'm not sure why that's relevant here.

Comment: @terdon Strictly, it isn't required for the OP's question as written. I just noticed you unintentionally made something more robust/useful than was needed.

Comment: Is `aren’t` a word? If yes then this answer won't work because it'll convert `aren't` to `arent` and so won't be able to find `aren't` in the input, if no then this answer still won't work because that'd mean `aren` and `t` are separate words but since the script converts `aren't` to `arent` it won't be able to find `aren` or `t` in the input. It has other issues too due to deleting punctuation rather than converting it to blanks and swapping the order of the `tr`s (which would work for one interpretation of "word").

Comment: To be clear - do not do `tr -d '[:punct:]'` as that concatenates strings that were separated by punctuation and so it'll create words that weren't actually present in your input while removing words that were present. Do `'tr '[[:space:][:punct:]]' '\n' < file` instead - it's still not a perfect approach but it's an improvement assuming you do want to treat punctuation chars like the `’` in `aren’t` as not word-constituent.

Comment: @EdMorton dammit, you keep raising very valid points! :) Yes, you're right, but if you're going to do proper natural language processing, you can't use this sort of naive tool anyway. It would also choke on *O'Reiley*  or *double-barreled*... Still, your `tr` is indeed an improvement worth making even if it's still flawed, it's less flawed than what I came up with. Thanks!

Comment: If you replace punctuation with whitespace in the text, then apply the same transformation to the search key, you'll find things like `aren't` will match correctly.

Comment: @Roaima you can't do that because then you can't tell which strings contained white space vs punctuation in the original text and the string you're trying to match on as 1 word might match 2 original words, etc.

Comment: The output contains `the` and `The` as different words (which may be argued that they aren't ((or they are??)) ). Maybe a `grep -inFx` would help in such cases.

Comment: A `tr -d '[[:space:][:punct:]]' '\n' < file` won't work with GNU tr. Maybe `tr -s '[[:space:][:punct:]]' '\n' < file`  would get the same result.

Comment: _sigh_. In my defense, I'm still working and it's 11pm... Nevertheless, I look forward to the day you get editing privileges here @EdMorton :)

Comment: @EdMorton I do not know the intent of terdon. He wrote the `-d`, he should change it, if he sees the change as valid.

Comment: @Isaac I did not. Ed suggested the neat `[[:space:][:punct:]]` approach in a comment and I just copied one of the previous lines and added that, but forgot to remove the `-d`. So no, not valid at all, just me being careless.

Comment: Maybe a `-s` (instead of the `-d`) to ensure that repeated spaces (or punctuation) is converted to **one** newline. Not necessarily the source file is "clean" as the example here and might contain repeated spaces, tabs or else.

Comment: @Isaac yes, that's a good point. But I think we have reached the limits of what is reasonable to do with this sort of naive tools. If we need want proper natural language processing, we would need different tools.

Comment: Ohhh, sure, all answers are imperfect solutions for an human language problem. You are most correct, sir.

Answer (score 3):

Use the tr command to replace all whitespace by a single newline (using the squeeze option).

Pipe that to nl -ba, which numbers each line (and thus word) sequentially.

Pipe that to grep -F for the word you want. This will show the number and text for just those words.

awk would also do this in one process, but probably look more complex.

Comment: `<FILE tr -s '[:space:]' '\n' | grep -nFi iphone`

Comment: With grep -n, I get `88:Seq`. With nl -ba, I get `    88 Seq` in columns. Actually, the OP asked just for the word numbers. I would change the grep to `awk '/^myWord$/ { print NR }` or to some variant of col. The significant part is using tr to serialise the words, though.

Comment: This would be much better if you actually showed the commands instead of just describing them.

Comment: I hadn't even thought of 'tr' but it makes this fairly simple. Thanks!

Comment: @terdon. I assumed from the OP that Johnny had command experience, and just needed a hint on using tr (to reduce a 2-D word array to 1-D). Personally, I would rethink the problem to produce a reference file, as a one-per-line sorted list of words in column 1, with the word numbers for that word following it horizontally. Having a script where you need to know that iPhone is in there to ask about it, seems unhelpful.

Comment: That's understandable, but remember that we don't answer for the person who asked. We answer for all the people who will read the question in the future, so even if the OP knows how to convert this into specific commands, the next person might not, so it's always better to at least show the commands.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative with `sed`:

```
sed -e '/^$/d' -e 's/^[[:blank:]]*//g' < file | sed 's/[[:blank:]]/\n/g' | grep -ion "iphone"
```

Output:

```
25:iPhone
54:iPhone
58:iPhone
```

Answer (score 1):

I was experimenting (right now!) with something similar: a word count. Like that, you see what the "words" look like:

```
]# cat iphone | tr -s [:space:] '\n' |sort|uniq -c|sort -n  |grep phone
      1 phone,
      1 phones
      1 phones,

]# cat iphone | tr -d [:punct:] | tr -s [:space:] '\n' |sort|uniq -c|sort -n  |grep phone
      1 phone
      2 phones
```

This trick(?) `|sort|uniq -c|sort -n` gives a good overview.

```
  2 Apple
  2 Pro
  2 a
  2 and
  2 company
  2 more
  2 phones
  2 to
  3 11
  3 iPhone
  3 its
  4 at
  6 the
```

This looks nice, but at the top:

```
  1 1000
  1 1100
  1 700
  1 750
  1 90minute
```

Dollars, comma and minus are gone...looks clean, at least.

---

A quick fix is defining some common interpuncts that will not appear in a (natural language) "word". And then use ^anchoring$, on one or both sides.

```
]# cat iphone | tr -d '.,;"!?' | tr -s [:space:] '\n' | grep -n phone 
21:phones
30:phone
72:phones

]# cat iphone | tr -d '.,;"!?' | tr -s [:space:] '\n' | grep -n ^phone$
30:phone
```

---

And you can locate things like small-digit numbers:

```
]# cat iphone | tr -d '.,;"!?' | tr -s [:space:] '\n' | grep -n '1[012]'
27:11
56:11
60:11
64:$1000
66:$1100
```

---

### `tr|sed|grep` (best simple solution)

This handles some cases (well all the ones in this @*#! text;) and gives 81 words, like `wc`. There must be no leading spaces to be correct with numbering. The stupid (but not too) splitting is done by `tr`, then `sed` removes the trailing punctuations: here only comma and period. And then a `grep` numbers and filters ad lib.

```
]# <iphone  tr -s ' \t' '\n' | sed -E 's/(.+)[.,]/\1/' | grep -En  '[\$-]|campus|i*[pP]hone$|entry' 
25:iPhone
28:entry-level
29:phone
33:$700
36:$750
54:iPhone
58:iPhone
63:$1000
65:$1,100
74:90-minute
81:campus
```

This `i*[pP]hone$` does *not* find the plural form. This would not work well with the trailing comma, see above. The commas are gone, except for the prices.

To separate "entry-level" you can just add the minus sign to `tr`'s SET1.

I think this is a good example of each tool doing one natural step.

Answer (score 0):

Create a function.

```
$ whereword(){ grep -ion "$1" -<<<$(egrep -o "[^[:blank:]]+" "$2"); }

$ whereword iPhone tmp.txt
25:iPhone
54:iPhone
58:iPhone

$ whereword "aren't" tmp.txt
14:aren't
```

Answer (score 0):

[I wonder how you got those numbers -- if I select the text up to the 1st `iPhone` and pipe it to `wc -w`, I get 24. Up the 2nd `iPhone`, I get 53, not 54. So they don't match, no matter in which direction I shift them]

Assuming that **a)** the count should be 1-based, **b)** words are separated by spaces (using the same definition of "word" as `wc -w`), and **c)** GNU grep is used, this will do much simpler:

```
grep -Po '\S+' file | grep -n iPhone

25:iPhone
54:iPhone
58:iPhone
```

[that will also match `iPhoney` or `XiPhone`, but not `iphone`; if you want to make it match the whole word case insensitively, use `... | grep -nwi iPhone`]

That's also more easily adaptable to a different definition of "word"; for instance, for word = a sequence of any characters except controls, spaces (separators) and punctuation:

```
grep -Po '[^\pC\pZ\pP]+' file | grep -n iPhone

26:iPhone
56:iPhone
60:iPhone
```

Or word = letters, marks, numbers and some symbols and punctuation like `$`, `_`, `'` + the unproperly used "left quotation mark" (U+2019) instead of apostrophe in `aren’t`:

```
grep -Po "[\pL\pM\pN'\x{2019}\$]+" file | grep -n iPhone

25:iPhone
55:iPhone
59:iPhone
```

Comment: This works (also): `grep -Eo '\S+' file| grep -n '[Pp]hones*'`. Btw. `tr` inserts a newline before the text starts, like your second example (from +1 to +2)

Answer (score 0):

Using the most common interpretation of "word" for parsing English text (i.e. what `grep -w` considers a word and what `\w` means in tools that accept that as meaning "word constituent character" in regexps) which is "a string of letters, digits, and/or underscore characters" `aren’t` is not a word so:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS="[^[:alnum:]_]+" }
{
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        numWords++
        if ($i == tgt) {
            print numWords
        }
    }
}

$ awk -v tgt="iPhone" -f tst.awk file
26
57
61

$ awk -v tgt="aren’t" -f tst.awk file
$

$ awk -v tgt="aren" -f tst.awk file
14
```

or if `aren’t` is a word then:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS="[^[:alnum:]_’]+" }
{
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        numWords++
        if ($i == tgt) {
            print numWords
        }
    }
}

$ awk -v tgt="iPhone" -f tst.awk file
25
56
60

$ awk -v tgt="aren’t" -f tst.awk file
14

$ awk -v tgt="aren" -f tst.awk file
$
```

The right solution all depends on your definition of a "word". For example neither of the above consider `$1,000` to be a word - idk if that's a problem or not for your application. If it is, here's a script that might be closer to your interpretation of a "word" (using GNU awk for FPAT):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    FPAT = "([[:alpha:]]+[’'][[:alpha:]]+)|([$]?[0-9]+(,[0-9]+)*([.][0-9]+)?%?)|([[:alnum:]_]+)"
}
{
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        numWords++
        print numWords, "<" $i ">"
        if ($i == tgt) {
            print numWords
        }
    }
}
```

and here's the "words" it recognizes in your sample input:

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
1 <On>
2 <Tuesday>
3 <in>
4 <a>
5 <sign>
6 <that>
7 <Apple>
8 <is>
9 <paying>
10 <attention>
11 <to>
12 <consumers>
13 <who>
14 <aren’t>
15 <racing>
16 <to>
17 <buy>
18 <more>
19 <expensive>
20 <phones>
21 <the>
22 <company>
23 <said>
24 <the>
25 <iPhone>
26 <11>
27 <its>
28 <entry>
29 <level>
30 <phone>
31 <would>
32 <start>
33 <at>
34 <$700>
35 <compared>
36 <with>
37 <$750>
38 <for>
39 <the>
40 <comparable>
41 <model>
42 <last>
43 <year>
44 <Apple>
45 <kept>
46 <the>
47 <starting>
48 <prices>
49 <of>
50 <its>
51 <more>
52 <advanced>
53 <models>
54 <the>
55 <iPhone>
56 <11>
57 <Pro>
58 <and>
59 <iPhone>
60 <11>
61 <Pro>
62 <Max>
63 <at>
64 <$1,000>
65 <and>
66 <$1,100>
67 <The>
68 <company>
69 <unveiled>
70 <the>
71 <new>
72 <phones>
73 <at>
74 <a>
75 <90>
76 <minute>
77 <press>
78 <event>
79 <at>
80 <its>
81 <Silicon>
82 <Valley>
83 <campus>
```

Comment: No, `wc` (and that is what the OP used to get the word count) define word (from man wc) as *A word is a non-zero-length sequence of characters delimited by white space.*, so no: that's clearly not the same as `\w`.

Comment: @Isaac I didn't mention `wc`. I know the OP used it but the OP doesn't know how to solve his problem. Did you maybe mean to comment on the question or on a different answer?

Answer (score 0):

A GNU `awk` alternative, splitting on single spaces or the combination of a full stop and a newline

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS=" |\\.\n"} $0~/iPhone/{print NR}' file1
```

Answer (score 0):

To keep up with the idea that a word is what `wc` counts as a word:

> A word is a non-zero-length sequence of characters delimited by white space.

We can divide the file into sequences of non-spaces in each line with `grep -Eo '[^[:space:]]+' file`, then remove `tr -d '[:punct:]'` the (still present) punctuation characters, and finally, grep (case insensitive) by the word of interest `grep -in 'phone'`

```
$ grep -Eo '[^[:space:]]+' file | tr -d '[:punct:]' | grep -in 'phone'
20:phones
25:iPhone
29:phone
54:iPhone
58:iPhone
71:phones
```

Note that the removal of punctuation characters in this case doesn't change the line position of the words. The `-i` option selects both `Phone` and `phone` as shown.

For the case of the word `iPhone`:

```
$ grep -Eo '[^[:space:]]+' file | tr -d '[:punct:]' | grep -in 'iphone'
25:iPhone
54:iPhone
58:iPhone
```

That should be the correct word numbering (Not 24, 54 and 58 as you wrote).